# How to format a string column as a int column?

Tags: powerbi

I have a table where the first column has values that represent a duration in the following format "xd yh wm zs" as a text. I want to format these text into a integer value that represents this duration in seconds. How could I achieve this in power BI?

Answer (score 0):

Power BI cant handle this situations very good. Nomrally you have to write custom functions or convert it yourself. The best way here would be, you go to `Edit Querires > Transform > Split Column By Delimiter` and chose the following

[image]

and then add the following custom column (`Add Column > Custom Column`)

[image]